# How to safely secure tailgate bench to studs

Tags: wood, fasteners

I have a old 1950s truck tailgate which measures 49 3/4 inches wide and 24 inches tall. I want to turn into a bench that will fold up and down that will mount to a wall. The wall has standard 2x4 16 inch spacing studs. I have put together a picture of how I am thinking of doing this. My idea was using 2 side supports along with a bottom footer that would attach to the wall using 4 3/8 inch lag screws and 3 along the bottom. The side supports would be made by gluing together a 3.5 inch wide x 24 inch and 2.5 inch wide x 24 hard maple. I would place the lag screws on the 3.5 inch wide portion so that the screws will be hidden when the tailgate is in the up position. I believe this should hold but I keep talking myself out of it. I also was concerned of the eye hook plate for holding the chain to the tailgate will be taking a large portion of the load as well it would be about 2 inches big with 4 screws holding them in place  [image]

edit: The intended use of this is to be a seating bench.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone can answer this. Use large enough fasteners, enough of them, secured well enough. The chain will give if it gives depending on load. If by "bench" you mean a work bench, then no matter what you do this will be for the lightest of workloads because benches see more racking and dynamic forces than static loads. So maybe [edit] this question and tell us what the intended use is.

Comment: Is it a workbench? A seating area (that would be cool!)? A bar for serving drinks? Purely decorative? As jdv said, the use will determine the strength of mounting required.

Comment: Sorry I edited the original post I thought I had included it but I guess not. I intend for this to be a seating bench.

Comment: Do the sides of your wood frame line up with studs ? I do not like the eye hook, use through bolts not screws. I would use eye bolts that have machine threads, drill a hole through the wood and recess the nut and two wide washers.

Comment: the wood frame will extend past the stud on each side by about 1 or 2 inches past where the lag screws would go. I really like your idea of using a eye bolt! that would make me feel a lot better than using the eye hook plate . I also may do the same thing using through bolts for the hinges on the bottom of the tailgate as well.

Comment: I have had a dream kicking around my brain for making one of these for quite some time. My though was to have it built into a non load bearing wall so when in the up position it is flush with the wall. People would say oh, interesting idea for art, and i would lift the handle, put the tailgate down and have a seat. Are you going to wire up the tail lights ?

Comment: That would be really cool! Yea I am getting some lights that are vintage replicas of the year of the truck. I'm thinking of routing a groove in the back of the bottom footer that the wires will go and mount a plug on the side

Comment: As far as weight on the chains goes, consider what holds up a "real" tailgate on an actual truck. It's usually a stud welded into the tailgate surround which a special link hooks over, or there's a special link at the end that slips into a pocket in the vertical post. Consider how many people sit on tailgates (or put huge loads on them hauling stuff home from the big box store). No recommendation here, just food for thought.